# SharePoint 2013 list does not export all data to Excel

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list, excel, sharepoint-list

hello guys I got SharePoint list with 13879 items and when I am trying to export data to Excel, it only exports part of this Data (352 items).

also when I am scrolling List page to page it only shows 352 item

[image]

but actually there are 13879 items

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you check if there is filter applied on the view from where you are exporting the excel?

Try opening allitems.aspx (hope this view is not filtered) else you can create brand new view (without any filters) and then try to export it from that view. It should bring everything to excel.